# Unique pair in the Vector list C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector of pairs of integers that looks somehow like that:

(0, 1)
(1, 9)
(0, 1)
(2, 4)
(1, 9)
I want to extract unique pairfrom there, so that the result looks as follows:
(0,1)
(1,9)
(2, 4)

At the moment I'm doing it like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getElements(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& S) {
    std::vector<int> V;
    V.reserve(2 * S.size());
    for (const auto& i : S) {
        V.push_back(i.first);
        V.push_back(i.second);
    }
    std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
    V.erase(std::unique(V.begin(), V.end()), V.end());
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{ { 0, 1 },{ 1, 9 },{ 0, 1 },{ 2, 4 },{ 1, 9 } };

    for (const auto& i : getElements(v))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

I am getting - ‍‍0‍, 1, 2, 4, 9

Any corrections in code will be helpful

Comment: Why are you returning a list of numbers if you need a list of pairs? You could just use `std::set` which will ensure the uniqueness for you.

Comment: `pair` is a value type like any other, like for example `int`. So solve your problem for `vector<int>` and then replace that `int` with `std::pair<int, int>` once everything works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

1. `getElements` should return `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`, since you mentioned you would like to get the unique pairs.
2. The last few lines of code in `getElements` is in the direction of the right solution. As you can see here: [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), sort followed by unique can be used to remove all duplicates. But all the code creating a `vector` of `int`s from the `pair`s should not be there.

See below a corrected version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> getElements(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> const & S) {
    auto V = S;
    std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
    V.erase(std::unique(V.begin(), V.end()), V.end());
    return V;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{ { 0, 1 },{ 1, 9 },{ 0, 1 },{ 2, 4 },{ 1, 9 } };
    for (const auto& i : getElements(v))
        std::cout << "(" << i.first << "," << i.second << ")  ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
(0,1)  (1,9)  (2,4)
```

**Update:** as @JHBonarius commented below, since `getElements` does not modify `S`, it is better to pass it by `const &` (see my updated code above).
This way the compiler will detect an erroneous attempt to modify it.

Comment: Small improvement: As you're not modifying `S`, it can be passed as a const-ref. OR, you pass by value and name it `V`, as you would else make the copy in the next line anyhow.

Comment: @JHBonarius good point. Will update my answer.

Comment: Suppose if the input is as below:
(0, 1) 
(1, 9) 
(1, 0) 
(2, 4) 
(1, 9)

I am geeting this below 
(0, 1) 
(1, 9) 
(2, 4)

(1,0)  - i dnt want this as we have pair(0,1)

Comment: @sharan a `std::pair` is **ordered** by defintion. Therefore (0,1) is not the same as (1,0). If you want to treat them as equals, you should post a new question (rather than editing the current one and thus changing its meaning).

Comment: @sharan if you prefer not to post a new question, then an easy solution for treating (x,y) and (y,x) as equivalent, would be to make sure V contains pairs where the first element <= second element. You can do that by adding the following after `auto V = S;` : `for (auto & v :V) { if (v.first > v.second) { std::swap(v.first, v.second); }}`